# How to get listview column lines with dynamically changing column width in MVVM pattern

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm

I have a list view in wpf, with 3 comboboxes and 2 checkbox as columns. I play with checkbox visibility based on some search criteria. I could achieve horizontal line between rows, however i could not achieve vertical line to separate columns. I change the visibility of checkbox & column width from my model.I need to follow MVVM pattern. 
Help much appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Below is my xaml code

```
<ListView  Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" 
                           ItemsSource="{Binding NewTransactionSetlist,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNewItem,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                           SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedNewIndex, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                           VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="320"  SelectionMode="Single" 
                          HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="1240">
                    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,2"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,1"/>
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                            <!--<EventSetter Event="PreviewGotKeyboardFocus" Handler="SelectCurrentItem" ></EventSetter>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="true">
                                        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="true" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>-->
                            <!--<Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"  />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>-->

                        </Style>
                    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <!--<i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewGotKeyboardFocus">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PreviewGotKeyboardFocusCommand}" 
                                                  />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>-->
                    <!--<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                         <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"  />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>-->
                    <ListView.InputBindings>
                        <KeyBinding 
                         Key="Delete" 
                         Command="{Binding NewTransactionDataGridRowDeleteCommand}"/>
                    </ListView.InputBindings>
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewHeaderStyle}">
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Transaction" Width="{Binding NewTransactionHeaderLength,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"   >
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                            <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxParamList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="{Binding TransactionHeaderLength,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                  IsEditable="False" Style="{DynamicResource DatagridComboboxFontstyle}" 
                                              Text="{Binding ParamGroup, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                              SelectedValue ="{Binding ParamGroup, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                              ItemsSource="{Binding ParamGroupList}" >
                                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                                                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.ParameterNewSelectionChangedCommand, 
                                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"/>
                                                </i:EventTrigger>
                                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                        </ComboBox>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="System" Width="{Binding NewSystemHeaderLength,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                            <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxSystemList"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="{Binding SystemHeaderLength,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                  IsEditable="False" Style="{DynamicResource DatagridComboboxFontstyle}" 
                                              Text="{Binding SystemName, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                              SelectedValue ="{Binding SystemName, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                              ItemsSource="{Binding SystemNameList}"   />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="HandAdd" Width="{Binding NewHandAddHeaderLength,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                            <CheckBox Name="CheckBoxNewHandAdd" Width="{Binding HandAddHeaderLength,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                  Visibility="{Binding HandAddVisibility,Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}"  
                                                  IsChecked="{Binding HandAdd, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, 
                                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="90,0,0,0" ></CheckBox>
                                    </DataTemplate>                                        
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Downstream" Width="{Binding NewDownstreamHeaderLength,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                            <CheckBox Width="{Binding DownstreamHeaderLength,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
                                                  Visibility="{Binding DownstreamVisibility,Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}" 
                                                  IsChecked="{Binding Downstream, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, 
                                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Margin="90,0,0,0"></CheckBox>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Node" Width="{Binding NewNodeHeaderLength,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                            <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxNodeList" Width="{Binding NodeHeaderLength,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                  Text="{Binding Node, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, 
                                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                                  SelectedValue ="{Binding Node, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, 
                                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  IsEditable="False" Style="{DynamicResource DatagridComboboxFontstyle}" 
                                              ItemsSource="{Binding NodeList}" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
```

Comment: so you want to show the gridlines on the grid? try https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.showgridlines(v=vs.105).aspx setting ShowGridLines = true in grid.

Comment: i am using .net framework 4.6, I don't find it in my assembly. How can i get that dll?

Comment: yes, try this blog http://blog.bulatgafurov.name/2010/06/listview-horizontal-and-vertical.html with that you can create vertical-horizontal grid lines.

Comment: Thanks mate ! It solved my problem..!

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.bulatgafurov.name/2010/06/listview-horizontal-and-vertical.html

this blog solved my problem...!